# Chromatic number of a graph with no 4 cycles.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

> Suppose $G$ is graph with no $4$-cycles. Let $n$ be the number of vertices of $G$. How can I show that the chromatic number of $G$ is $O(\sqrt{n})$?

[The analogous fact about $3$-cycles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571308/upper-bound-on-chig-for-a-triangle-free-graph) is well-known.

Answer (score 2):

Let the graph $G$ have $n$ vertices with degrees $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n$ and average degree $d = \frac1n(d_1 + \dots + d_n)$. We will first show that if $G$ is $C_4$-free, then $d$ cannot be too large, then show that this means $G$ has a large independent set, then iterate to show that $G$ has a small chromatic number. (If this strategy sounds workable, try it for yourself.)

For the first step, we begin by relating the number of 3-vertex paths in $G$ to the average degree $d$. To choose a path on 3 vertices in $G$, we choose a middle vertex $v$, and then choose two of its neighbors $w_1, w_2$. This can be done in $$\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{d_i}{2} \ge n \binom{d}{2}$$ ways, where the inequality follows by convexity of $f(x) = \binom x2$.

If there are more than $\binom n2$ such paths, then by pigeonhole two of them must have the same endpoints, which would make a 4-cycle. We can't have that, so $n \binom d2 \le \binom n2$, which means $d = O(\sqrt n)$.

This was, by the way, a special case of the Kővári–Sós–Turán theorem.

For the second step, we will pick an independent set by the following strategy: sort the vertices at random, and let $I$ be the set of vertices sorted before their neighbors. Then $I$ is an independent set, and the probability that a vertex with degree $d_i$ ends up in $I$ is $\frac1{d_i + 1}$. So the expected number of vertices in $I$ is $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{d_i + 1} \ge \frac n{d+1}$$ where the inequality follows by convexity of $f(x) = \frac1{x+1}$. There must be an independent set of size at least this expected value, and in our case, $\frac n{d+1} = \Omega(\sqrt n)$.

This was, by the way, one of the versions of Turán's theorem, though that's usually stated for cliques and not independent sets.

Finally, we can color the graph $G$ greedily: pick out the largest independent set $I$, give it a color, and repeat this for $G-I$. The remaining graph is also $C_4$-free, so the same argument applies to it, and coloring square-root many vertices at each step colors the entire graph in $O(\sqrt n)$ steps.

Comment: Also try to bound the number of steps before you are left with $(1-\alpha)n$. This number is at most \[ \frac{\alpha n}{\sqrt{(1-\alpha)n}} \] and repeating this procedure, you get a bound on the number of steps equal to about number of \[ \{\alpha \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{1-\alpha}(1-\alpha)} \] which tends to 2\sqrt{n} as $\alpha$ grows small. , if we write $N(t)$ an upper bound on the number of vertices at step $t$, then the difference equation $N(t+1) = N(t) - \sqrt{N(t)}$ is identical to the differential equation $\frac{dN}{dt} = -\sqrt n$ so $N(t) = (C-t/2)^2$ with $C=n$. Note $N(2\sqrt n) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, we have to be a bit more careful than I was about how many coloring steps we actually need. (Though if we just want an $O(\sqrt n)$ upper bound in the end, we don't need anything more complicated than running your argument with any $\alpha < 1$, such as $\alpha = \frac12$.)